# Переход с Newtonsoft.Json на Utf8.Json

Tags: c#, json

По словам автора, Utf8.Json значительно быстрее и меньше ест памяти, и притом столь же функционален, как и Newtonsoft.Json.

В чем суть - получаются разные объекты.

строка на входе

```
 string raw = {"_id":"1","battles":7,"forces":22,"persons":[32,41,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,29,29,23,22,22,23,9,10,9,9,9,9,9,9,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2],"shop":0}
```

В случае NewtonSoft.Json

```
k =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(raw);
```

получается вот такой вот отформатированный тот же json

```
 k = {
"_id": "1",
"battles": 7,
"forces": 22,
"persons": [
32,
41,
32,
32,
32,
32,
32,
32,
32,
32,
32,
32,
32,
32,
32,
32,
32,
29,
29,
23,
22,
22,
23,
9,
10,
9,
9,
9,
9,
9,
9,
6,
6,
6,
6,
5,
5,
5,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
2
],
"shop": 0,
}
```

А вот в случае Utf8.Json

```
k = Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(raw);
```

получается Dictionary такого вида

Как сделать, чтобы он возвращал отформатированную строку, как NewtonSoft.Json?

```
key - value
_id     1
battles 7
```

Ну и тд и тп. Т.е. он превращает JSON в Dictionary.

Если я просто делаю

```
k = Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(raw);
```

То получаю ошибку

```
JsonParsingException: expected:'String Begin Token', actual:'{', at offset:0
```

Comment: Вы путаете объект и его строковое представление. Метод `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` никогда не возвращал вам строку!

Comment: А превратить словарь в строку вы всегда можете методом `Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize`

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, вы правы. Когда я запросил `getType` то получил `Newtonsoft.JObject`, а та строка с переносами была строковым представлением этого объекта. Т.к. `JObject` является классом Newtonsoft.Json, то, вероятно десериализация в него будет не таким простым делом из стороннего сериализатора.

Comment: А зачем вам десериализовывать именно в него? Используйте тот словарь что вам вернул Utf8Json.

Comment: @PavelMayorov очень много используется в проекте JObject, всё сразу не убрать. А десериализация очень притормаживает, хотел библиотеку побыстрее поставить

Comment: Ну так проблема-то в чем?

Comment: @PavelMayorov в том чтобы десериализовать JSON в JObject быстрее, чем это может сделать сам десериализатор Newtonsoft.Json, без избавления от JObject-ов

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86129/discussion-between-dmitrii-and-pavel-mayorov).